# SQL query to count distinct count from 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have SQL table named table

```
Document    Word
-------------------
doc1    Hello
doc1    Hi
doc1    Welcome
doc1    Hello
doc2    Welcome
doc2    Welcome
doc3    Hi
doc3    Hello
doc3    Good Luck
```

This means I have list of documents, each document contains some words, and I have raw for each word per each document, and if a word appeared twice in the same document I will have 2 raws.
I want to get a list of distinct words with how many documents it appeared in, regardless how many times it appeared.
So the output from this table should be

```
Hello: 2 --> which means it appeared in 2 documents
Hi: 2
Welcome: 2
Good Luck: 1
```

Can anyone please help me in writing the query that will return this result?

Answer (score 3):

You want `count(distinct)`:

```
select word, count(distinct document)
from t
group by word;
```